# Error in deploying DXA 2.0 Java on linux server "Cannot find cache named 'model-service'"

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java

We are trying to deploy DXA 2.0 CTP 2 Java version on Ubuntu server. After deploying the application on Tomcat 8 we are getting this server error

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-6] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'model-service' for CacheResultOperation[CacheMethodDetails[method=public java.lang.Object com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.ModelServiceClient.getForType(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object[]) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaItemNotFoundException, cacheAnnotation=@javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult(cacheKeyGenerator=interface javax.cache.annotation.CacheKeyGenerator, cacheName=model-service, cachedExceptions=[class com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaItemNotFoundException, class com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.exception.BadRequestException], skipGet=false, cacheResolverFactory=interface javax.cache.annotation.CacheResolverFactory, exceptionCacheName=failures, nonCachedExceptions=[]), cacheName='model-service']]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver.resolveCaches(AbstractCacheResolver.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInterceptor.resolveCache(AbstractCacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.CacheResultInterceptor.invoke(CacheResultInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheAspectSupport.execute(JCacheAspectSupport.java:131)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheAspectSupport.execute(JCacheAspectSupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheInterceptor.invoke(JCacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.ModelServiceClient$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d94710a3.getForType(<generated>)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.DefaultModelService._loadPage(DefaultModelService.java:52)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.DefaultModelService.loadPageModel(DefaultModelService.java:39)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider._loadPage(DefaultContentProvider.java:48)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getPageModel(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:82)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:292)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1460)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

All SDL micro services are up and running.

**Edit**

I have followed below steps to generate deployment package (war file)

1. Generate project using  mvn archetype:generate command.
2. Setup project on my Local PC (Windows 7) using Eclipse and Tomcat 8.
3. Run the project on local Tomcat and it worked fine.
4. Run mvn clean package cmd on project directory and generate production build (war file) and deploy on Linux server Tomcat but this time I get server error.

Comment: Have you setup the DXA Model Service following the documentation? Please **edit** the question and provide a bit more detail on what was done and tried etc.

Comment: @BartKoopman please check the edits

Comment: Seeing point #3 I'm guessing you have setup the DXA Model Service (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v9/GUID-2CF89E5B-D84C-498F-A65A-920EFC26A5A4) on the CIS server, so then I'm wondering if the Tomcat on your Linux server has the same version requirements and Java version installed etc. But other than that I don't have much clues.

Comment: @BartKoopman i m using Apache Tomcat/8.0.32  and JAVA 8

Comment: Similar question on https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/f/198/t/15469

Comment: @BartKoopman  when i disable web application caching using spring.profiles.active=dxa.no-cache inside dxa.properties file then website loaded on linux machine so there is some problem related to cache

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to DXA 2.0 the issue get resolved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your cache config has all the caches configured like in the following file
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/DXA_2.0_CTP_2_Release/dxa-webapp/src/main/resources/ehcache-dxa.xml

For CTP2 release full configuration was still needed, for the future 2.0 release application will be smarter and automatically resolve that kind of issues.